# How does angular define whether aot compiler should be used

Tags: javascript, angular

[This page](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/ngmodule.html) about modules states that there are two approaches to bootstrapping - dynamic and static. They are configured only in `main.ts`:

```
// The browser platform with a compiler
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';

// The app module
import { AppModule } from './app.module';

// Compile and launch the module
platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule);
```

versus static (aot compiler):

```
// The browser platform without a compiler
import { platformBrowser } from '@angular/platform-browser';

// The app module factory produced by the static offline compiler
import { AppModuleNgFactory } from './app.module.ngfactory';

// Launch with the app module factory.
platformBrowser().bootstrapModuleFactory(AppModuleNgFactory);
```

My question is how does angular know that aot compiler should be used? There seem to be no option to indicate that. I doubt that it parses `main.ts` and checks whether I used `@angular/platform-browser'` or `@angular/platform-browser-dynamic'`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not just importing a different module: the whole set-up is different.

**In the dynamic scenario**, your `AppModule` is loaded through the `platformBrowserDynamic` loader. This object knows how to JIT-compile the rest of the modules in your application.

**In the static scenario**, you instead provide an `AppModuleNgFactory` to the `platformBrowser` loader. This other object knows where to find the AOT-compiled files of the application.

Think about it this way: angular cannot decide on the spot whether to use the AOT compiler or not, because that wouldn't be *ahead of time*! What it *does* decide is whether to search for existing compiled files, or to generate them locally. The precompiled files already exist: it's only a matter of going after them or not.

As for deciding whether to compile the files AOT, note that the Typescript compiler configuration (stored in `tsconfig.json`) is also different. The `angularCompilerOptions` section enables AOT compilation.

Documentation: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/aot-compiler.html

Comment: thanks, but `AppModuleNgFactory` is generated by compiler, isn't it? so between this line `import { platformBrowser } from '@angular/platform-browser';` and this line `import { AppModuleNgFactory } from './app.module.ngfactory';` the decision to use aot is made. no?

Comment: I added a paragraph to complete the answer =)

Comment: thanks, so it's a bit misleading how they put it. it's actually a last step after all other numerous steps are performed from the link you provided. and of course the `AppModuleNgFactory` is ready after `ngc` compilation even before this  line `import { platformBrowser } from '@angular/platform-browser';` is processed I guess